# Encrypted flashdrive

Tags: usb, encryption, flash-drive

I'm looking for a secure USB flash drive that has built-in 256-bit (or greater) encryption.

**Requirements:**

- At least 16GB
- USB 3.0
- Completely encrypted without third-party software.
- Having either actual buttons on the flash drive (for a pin), or having to type in a password when plugged into a computer is fine
- Works on both Windows (Vista, 7, 8.1, 10) and on GNU/Linux
- Able to change/customize password or pin
- Cheaper it is, the better, but no actual limit for the price
- Unable to delete files/format without the password/pin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kingston has a few excellent encrypted flash drive solutions. Their flash drives are always high-quality and are known for their reliability.

**[Kingston DataTraveler Vault Privacy 3.0](http://www.kingston.com/us/usb/encrypted_security#dtvp30)**
Their basic encrypted flash drive. (~$60 for 16GB)

- encryption certified by FIPS 197 standard
- optional antivirus (I can't attest to the usefulness of this)

**[Kingston DataTraveler 4000 G2](http://www.kingston.com/us/usb/encrypted_security#dt4000G2)**
Their advanced encrypted flash drive. (~$70 for 16GB)

- encryption certified by FIPS 140-2 Level 3, a higher standard than FIPS 197
- waterproof and titanium-coated stainless steel
- allows bulk-order customization (logo, encryption and password settings, etc.) for businesses
- a seal that shows signs of tampering if the encryption module is messed with

**Features of both models**

- 4GB to 64GB
- USB 3.0 and 2.0 connectivity
- built-in 256-bit XTS encryption
- works with Vista/7/8.1/10, OSX, and Linux
- optional read-only access mode
- lockdown/formatting protocol for attempted break-ins
- password-protected access and optional "dual password" to reset via the OS